# How do i access netstat data in ruby

Tags: ruby, jruby

I want list of all networking statistics like  network connections, routing tables and a number of network interface.  How can I do this in Ruby?

Comment: Can't you just shell out to netstat?

Comment: No, i want to use it by ruby or can say in a project.

Comment: `netstat_output = \`netstat\``

Comment: netstat_output = `netstat`, As far as i know its not any gem or plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I noted, you've tagged this as JRuby as well ... you can get some of the info using Java APIs.
but do not expect to get full routing as (`netstat` gives you) in the end a gem (or plugin) will use a system call anyways (at least on Java there's no way do get the tables cross-platform) ...

```
ifaces = java.net.NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces.to_a # all you have
name = ifaces[0].name # name = "number" of interface e.g. "eth0"
ips = ifaces[0].inet_addresses.map { |addr| addr.to_s } # likely IP6/IP4
```

Explore the API: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html

... you might find some of the "primitive" routing stuff with a few tricks, but not all :

[Is it possible to get the default gateway IP and MAC addresses in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382033/is-it-possible-to-get-the-default-gateway-ip-and-mac-addresses-in-java)

[Java finding network interface for default gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11797641/java-finding-network-interface-for-default-gateway)