# Get Wi-Fi name and interface in JAVA

Tags: java, networking, jakarta-ee, wifi

I am working on a JAVA project to list out all available Wi-FI interfacesand their network interfaces name.

this is my code:

```
Enumeration<NetworkInterface> a = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
    while (a.hasMoreElements()) {
          NetworkInterface ni = a.nextElement();
          if(ni.isUp()) {
               System.out.println(ni.getName());
          }
        }
```

This code returns all network interfaces including Wi-Fi interface:

```
lo
wlan0
```

But I want to get also the Wi-Fi interfcae name like this:

```
netowrk interface: "wlan0"
Wi-Fi name: "Wi-Fi"

netowrk interface: "wlan1"
Wi-Fi name: "Wi-Fi 1"
```

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Finding SSID of a wireless network with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5378103)

Comment: Thanks for your replay, but I want to get network interface and it equivalent name